# Jetty java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException thrown under load

Tags: java, jetty

I have a simple embedded Jetty setup which answers queries which under load occasionally exhibits the following error. If I run the same siege test it will always show 100% complete but occasionally Jetty throws the following exception.

I have a try catch in my code which isn't being triggered so it appears the exception is being caught by Jetty "under the hood". The SLF4J: message is definitely not mine!

Any ideas.!?

```
SLF4J: Failed toString() invocation on an object of type [org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection]MethodLogger.INIT 2016-09-28T09:51:18.325Z qtp992136656-31 SYSTEM_LOGGER : [Void org.twocows.adtexo.node.jena.dataset.SPARQLJenaDatasetHttpServlet.doGet(HttpServletRequest,HttpServletResponse)]#257 null
MethodLogger.RETURN_VOID 2016-09-28T09:51:18.325Z qtp992136656-31 SYSTEM_LOGGER : [Void org.twocows.adtexo.node.jena.dataset.SPARQLJenaDatasetHttpServlet.doGet(HttpServletRequest,HttpServletResponse)]#257 Void
MethodLogger.INIT 2016-09-28T09:51:18.325Z qtp992136656-35 SYSTEM_LOGGER : [Void org.twocows.adtexo.node.jena.dataset.SPARQLJenaDatasetHttpServlet.doGet(HttpServletRequest,HttpServletResponse)]#258 null
MethodLogger.RETURN_VOID 2016-09-28T09:51:18.325Z qtp992136656-35 SYSTEM_LOGGER : [Void org.twocows.adtexo.node.jena.dataset.SPARQLJenaDatasetHttpServlet.doGet(HttpServletRequest,HttpServletResponse)]#258 Void
MethodLogger.INIT 2016-09-28T09:51:18.325Z qtp992136656-31 SYSTEM_LOGGER : [Void org.twocows.adtexo.node.jena.dataset.SPARQLJenaDatasetHttpServlet$2.run()]#259 null
MethodLogger.INIT 2016-09-28T09:51:18.325Z qtp992136656-35 SYSTEM_LOGGER : [Void org.twocows.adtexo.node.jena.dataset.SPARQLJenaDatasetHttpServlet$2.run()]#260 null

Reported exception:
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.nio.Buffer.checkIndex(Buffer.java:540)
    at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.get(HeapByteBuffer.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.BufferUtil.appendDebugString(BufferUtil.java:1042)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.BufferUtil.toDetailString(BufferUtil.java:1021)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.toString(HttpConnection.java:809)
    at org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.safeObjectAppend(MessageFormatter.java:299)
    at org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.deeplyAppendParameter(MessageFormatter.java:271)
    at org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(MessageFormatter.java:233)
    at org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(MessageFormatter.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JettyAwareLogger.log(JettyAwareLogger.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JettyAwareLogger.debug(JettyAwareLogger.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog.debug(Slf4jLog.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.parseRequestBuffer(HttpConnection.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: What is/are names of your classes that you used?

Comment: What version of Jetty?